# Kafka Streams - reducing the memory footprint for large state stores

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a topology (see below) that reads off a very large topic (over a billion messages per day). The memory usage of this Kafka Streams app is pretty high, and I was looking for some suggestions on how I might reduce the footprint of the state stores (more details below). **Note:** I am not trying to scape goat the state stores, I just think there may be a way for me to improve my topology - see below.

```
// stream receives 1 billion+ messages per day
stream
    .flatMap((key, msg) -> rekeyMessages(msg))
    .groupBy((key, value) -> key)
    .reduce(new MyReducer(), MY_REDUCED_STORE)
    .toStream()
    .to(OUTPUT_TOPIC);

// stream the compacted topic as a KTable
KTable<String, String> rekeyedTable = builder.table(OUTPUT_TOPIC, REKEYED_STORE);


// aggregation 1
rekeyedTable.groupBy(...).aggregate(...)

// aggreation 2
rekeyedTable.groupBy(...).aggregate(...)

// etc
```

More specifically, I'm wondering if streaming the `OUTPUT_TOPIC` as a KTable is causing the state store (`REKEYED_STORE`) to be larger than it needs to be locally. For changelog topics with a large number of unique keys, would it be better to stream these as a `KStream` and do windowed aggregations? Or would that not reduce the footprint like I think it would (e.g. that only a subset of the records - those in the window, would exist in the local state store).

Anyways, I can always spin up more instances of this app, but I'd like to make each instance as efficient as possible. Here's my question:

- Are there any config options, general strategies, etc that should be considered for Kafka Streams app with this level of throughput?
- Are there any guidelines for how memory intensive a single instance should have? Even if you have a somewhat arbitrary guideline, it may be helpful to share with others. One of my instances is currently utilizing 15GB of memory - I have no idea if that's good/bad/doesn't matter.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With your current pattern

```
stream.....reduce().toStream().to(OUTPUT_TOPIC);
builder.table(OUTPUT_TOPIC, REKEYED_STORE)
```

you get two stores with the same content. One for the `reduce()` operator and one for reading the `table()` -- this can be reduced to one store though:

```
KTable rekeyedTable  = stream.....reduce(.);
rekeyedTable.toStream().to(OUTPUT_TOPIC); // in case you need this output topic; otherwise you can also omit it completely
```

This should reduce your memory usage notably.

About windowing vs non-windowing:

1. it's a matter of your required semantics; so simple switching from a non-windowed to a windowed reduce seems to be questionable.
2. Even if you can also go with windowed semantics, you would not necessarily reduce memory. Note, in aggregation case, Streams does not store the raw records but only the current aggregate result (ie, key + currentAgg). Thus, for a single key, the storage requirement is the same for both cases (a single window has the same storage requirement). At the same time, if you go with windows, you might actually need more memory as you get an aggregate pro key pro window (while you get just a single aggregate pro key in the non-window case). The only scenario you might save memory, is the case for which you 'key space' is spread out over a long period of time. For example, you might not get any input records for some keys for a long time. In the non-windowed case, the aggregate(s) of those records will be stores all the time, while for the windowed case the key/agg record will be dropped and new entried will be re-created if records with this key occure later on again (but keep in mind, that you lost the previous aggergate in this case -- cf. (1))

Last but not least, you might want to have a look into the guidelines for sizing an application: http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/sizing.html

Comment: Thanks Matthias! Also, if a record is no longer needed in the `REKEYED_STORE` following certain types of aggregations, would it be advisable for the Kafka Streams app to try to delete these specific records from the state store itself (in order to reduce the size)? Or should we always rely on the retention policy for cleaning up the state store? Anyways, I'll accept the answer, thanks again!

Comment: For non-windowed store, there is no retention policy. The underlying topic is compacted only. Thus, if you know, that you don't need a record anymore, you would need to delete it via a tombstone. But it's a little tricky to achieve...

Comment: oh, I hadn't read about deleting via tombstone records yet. thanks for pointing me to that. so if I determine that I no longer need a certain record, it sounds like I may be able to  map the value to null and rewrite the same key to the `REKEYED_STORE` in order to delete it. I'll give that a shot and see what happens. if there's any other advice you have regarding that, please let me know. otherwise, thank you so much for everything you else you helped me answer :)

Comment: YW :) Note, that your KTable has two parts: (1) the changelog topic and (2) the store. To delete from both, you would need to sent a "delete" record into your reduce (this delete record's value must *not* be null -- otherwise the record is dropped internally, because there is nothing to aggregate). If your special "delete record" is processed in your `Reducer` you should return `null` as aggregation result. This will write a `<key,null>` tombstone into you local store and the changelog topic and delete in both places. Does this make sense? Let me know if this works for you :)

Comment: A couple of quick questions regarding the tombstones. Will the key still appear in the local state store until the log cleaner runs again to delete the tombstone messages? Also, for very large state stores, is it recommended to manually alter the `delete.retention.ms` on the changelog and repartition topics to ensure they get cleaned frequently (maybe every hour)? Finally, do we need to call KafkaStreams.cleanup() at any point for the state store to actually remove the tombstones locally?

Comment: Just finding it a little tricky to verify locally but I did update the Reducer.apply method to return null when a key can be deleted. Anyways, I'll spend some more time on it today and see if I can verify that I set it up correctly :)

Comment: The key will be deleted from the local store immediately. `delete.retention.ms` applies to changelog topics (not to "regular" topics) -- no need to change this value, as it has very little impact on you application. `cleanup()` deletes the complete(!) local state -- thus, you should not call it at all (cf https://www.confluent.io/blog/data-reprocessing-with-kafka-streams-resetting-a-streams-application/)

Comment: I finally got the tombstones to work :)  it was a little tricky like you said, but it seems to be working great now! thanks again for your help!

Comment: Great! If you want to do a favor back, can you add this tombstone usage to https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Stream+Usage+Patterns -- we got this question multiple time and it would be awesome to have an example to point people to :) -- for wiki access, please share your wiki-id (you can create an account if you don't have one) and ask for permission at dev list (see http://kafka.apache.org/contact) :D

Comment: Sure, I'd be happy to. Just requested access via the mailing list :)

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot!