# Clean up changelog topic backing session windows

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We are aggregating in session windows by using the following code:

```
.windowedBy(SessionWindows.with(...))
.aggregate(..., ..., ...)
```

The state store that is created for us automatically is backed by a changelog topic with `cleanup.policy=compact`.

When redeploying our topology, we found that restoring the state store took much longer than expected (10+ minutes). The explanation seems to be that even though a session has been closed, it is still present in the changelog topic.

We noticed that session windows have a default maintain duration of one day but even after the inactivity + maintain durations have been exceeded, it does not look like messages are removed from the changelog topic.

a) Do we need to manually delete "old" (by our definition) messages to keep the size of the changelog topic under control? (This may be the case as hinted to by [1].)

b) Would it be possible to somehow have the changelog topic created with `cleanup.policy=compact,delete` and would that even make sense?

[1] A session store seems to be created internally by Kafka Stream's  `UnwindowedChangelogTopicConfig` (and not `WindowedChangelogTopicConfig`) which may make this comment from [Kafka Streams - reducing the memory footprint for large state stores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44770462/kafka-streams-reducing-the-memory-footprint-for-large-state-stores) relevant: "For non-windowed store, there is no retention policy. The underlying topic is compacted only. Thus, if you know, that you don't need a record anymore, you would need to delete it via a tombstone. But it's a little tricky to achieve... – Matthias J. Sax Jun 27 '17 at 22:07"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hitting a bug. I just created a ticket for this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7101.

I would recommend that you modify the topic config manually for fix the issue in your deployment.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up - and thank you (and the team) for your great work on Kafka Streams.